# sql I want to make one row if ua_pilot has 2 ua_type to be on one row

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    UA_TYPE, UA_SCHEDULED_START_TIME, ua_pilot_id, 
    ua_assignmentreason_abbrev, ua_scheduled_end_time,  
    UA_CANCEL_TIME,ua_noq_reason
FROM
    unavailabilityassignment
WHERE 
    UA_TYPE IN ('NOQ')
    AND UA_ASSIGNMENT_TIME > '2022-01-01' 
    AND ua_scheduled_start_time  > '2022-01-21'
    AND ua_assignmentreason_abbrev IN 'APMA'

UNION

SELECT
    UA_TYPE, UA_SCHEDULED_START_TIME, ua_pilot_id, 
    ua_assignmentreason_abbrev, ua_scheduled_end_time, 
    UA_CANCEL_TIME,ua_noq_reason
FROM
    unavailabilityassignment
WHERE
    UA_TYPE IN ('SCK')
    AND UA_ASSIGNMENT_TIME > '2022-01-01'
    AND ua_scheduled_start_time > '2022-01-21'

UNION

SELECT
    UA_TYPE, UA_SCHEDULED_START_TIME, ua_pilot_id,  
    ua_assignmentreason_abbrev, ua_scheduled_end_time, 
    UA_CANCEL_TIME,ua_noq_reason
FROM
    unavailabilityassignment
WHERE
    UA_NOQ_REASON IN 'APMA'
    AND ua_scheduled_start_time > '2022-01-21'
ORDER BY
    3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what db you are using, but you can `GROUP BY ua_pilot_id` and use a function like the MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT` when selecting the other fields you need. For example

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(UA_TYPE)
...the rest of your query...
GROUP BY ua_pilot_id
```